# How can I make my SQL statement smaller so it doesn't time out?

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I have the following problem.

I have three tables in my postgresql DB.

They are: package, cartype and packagecartype.

`package` refers to a thing that needs to be moved from A to B and has certain requirements for it. For example, one of the requirements is freightlimit, which indicates how big the car has to be that transports a package. So it has minfreight and maxfreight which makes a range, "Car needs to be able to transport at a minimum this much and at a maximum that much, for this package."

`cartype` is a table where I save types of cars, that has nothing more than a an id, a minfreight and maxfreight and a name.

A package can have multiple cartypes, which are saved in the table packagecartype.

It means you don't have to enter the min/max-freight for the package, instead you can give it one or multiple cartypes to indicate the freight range.

`packagecartype` has three columns, it's own id, the packageid and the cartypeid.

Now I want to build a search function, that make a sql statement and give me all packages within certain parameters.

One of the fields I want my search to have is minfreight and maxfreight, meaning it will give me back all packages that have min/maxfreight within the given range OR all packages that have cartypes within the given range.

My SQL statement currently looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM package WHERE
((COALESCE(package.maxfreight, (SELECT MAX(ct.maxfreight)
      FROM packagecartype AS pct
      LEFT JOIN cartype AS ct
      ON pct.cartypeid = ct.id
      WHERE pct.packageid = package.id)) >= $GIVEN_MIN_FREIGHT)
   AND (COALESCE(package.minfreight, (SELECT MIN(ct.minfreight)
      FROM packagecartype AS pct
      LEFT JOIN  cartype AS ct
      ON pct.cartypeid = ct.id
      WHERE pct.packageid = package.id)) <= $GIVEN_MAX_FREIGHT));
```

This works fine but it is way too slow.
It times out if I use it on a DB with more than a few dozen entries which is just not acceptable. But sadly I am not that good at SQL and don't know how to improve this.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT:

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` Output

```
Seq Scan on package  (cost=0.00..7474.80 rows=9 width=930) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: ((COALESCE(maxfreight, (SubPlan 1)) >= 10000) AND (COALESCE(minfreight, (SubPlan 2)) <= 20000))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 5
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=46.64..46.65 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=35.62..46.63 rows=4 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (ct.id = pct.packagetypeid)
                ->  Seq Scan on cartype ct  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                ->  Hash  (cost=35.50..35.50 rows=10 width=4) (never executed)
                      ->  Seq Scan on packagecartype pct  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=10 width=4) (never executed)
                            Filter: (packageid = package.id)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=46.64..46.65 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=35.62..46.63 rows=4 width=4) (never executed)
                Hash Cond: (ct_1.id = pct_1.cartypeid)
                ->  Seq Scan on cartype ct_1  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=8) (never executed)
                ->  Hash  (cost=35.50..35.50 rows=10 width=4) (never executed)
                      ->  Seq Scan on packagecartype pct_1  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=10 width=4) (never executed)
                            Filter: (packageid = package.id)
Planning time: 0.758 ms
Execution time: 0.105 ms
```

Comment: For an exact answer `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output is needed. But you'll probably win if you calculate the minimum and the maximum in a single `WITH` clause.

Comment: Hey Laurenz, I added the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output in the edit. What do you with calculate the min and max in a single WITH?

Comment: Also I should mention that I ran the EXPLAIN query on my test db with very little Data, which is why it was so quick and didn't run over many rows.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably more efficient to do the grouping once and join to the result:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM package p
  join (
    SELECT pct.cargoid, 
           MAX(ct.maxfreight) as max_freight, 
           MIN(ct.minfreight) as min_freight
    FROM packagecartype AS pct
      LEFT JOIN cartype AS ct ON pct.cartypeid = ct.id
    group by pct.cargoid
  ) m ON pct.cargoid = p.id
WHERE COALESCE(p.maxfreight, m.max_freight) >= $GIVEN_MIN_FREIGHT
  and COALESCE(p.minfreight, m.min_freight) <= $GIVEN_MAX_FREIGHT;
```

Comment: Definetively grouping once is the way to go. Also, considering PostgreSQL does not automatically add indexes on FKs, I would add the following indexes just to be on the safe side: `packagecartype (cartypeid)` and `packagecartype (packageid)`.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer, that I think is very good:

Considering PostgreSQL does not automatically add indexes on FKs, I would add the following indexes just to be on the safe side:

```
create index ix1234 on packagecartype (cartypeid);
create index ix1235 on packagecartype (packageid);
```